# How to display an image with openfiledialog and label wpf

Tags: wpf

im creating a program to display any image with openfiledialog and a label(this one to display the image) i also added a textbox to show the image path

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();



       
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".png";
        dlg.Filter = "JPEG Files (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|GIF Files (*.gif)|*.gif";


     
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();


        
        if (result == true)
        {
            
            string filename = dlg.FileName;

            textBox.Text = filename;
            Ima = new Image();
            Ima.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@dlg.FileName));
            label.Content = Ima;

        }
```

heres the xaml code of the label:

```
<Label x:Name="label1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="78" Margin="107,180,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="344"/>
```

The problem with this is that when i choose the image i want to display, the label doesn't show it.

Comment: How is `label` defined? Do you have a XAML markup?

Comment: Sorry for the late responde. By xaml markup, do you mean the xaml code

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: ok, the post is edited, you can see the xaml code for the label now

Comment: If you set the `Content` of the `Label` to something else, like a string, do you see it?

Comment: Yes, if i set the content to a string i see that string, but  when i select an image the label still doesnt change

Answer (score 0):

Xaml File

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Image  Name="servicePhoto" Height="100" Width="100" Stretch="Fill" />
    <Button Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="btnLoad" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200"   Click="ServiceImage_Click">Choose Image</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

.cs File

```
private void ServiceImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
            op.Title = "Select a picture";
            op.Filter = "All supported graphics|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png|" +
              "JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|" +
              "Portable Network Graphic (*.png)|*.png";
            if (op.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                servicePhoto.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(op.FileName));
            }
        }
```